# Resetting paused scrape, Scrapy

Tags: python, linux, scrapy

I know that with the command:

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

I can pause/resume scrapes with CTRL+C.

What I want to know is how I can reset the scrapy and start back at the beginning. Is there a file I need to delete/empty?

M.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should remove your `JOBDIR`

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
<ctr+C>
rm -rf crawls/somespider-1
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try.

Comment: Answer after testing

Comment: It did work. Thanks! Does this also mean that if I have my spider in the cloud, that I can resume scrapes from a different computer as well?